# Internal storage of Classes and Structs

Tags: c++, memory, object-persistence

I want to use pointer magikry to save a C++ class using the following method that writes byte data into a file:

```
result Osp::Io::File::Write (const void *buffer, int length);
```

- Parameters:

  - `buffer` — A pointer to the user-supplied buffer that contains byte data to be written
  - `length` — The buffer length in bytes
- Exceptions:

  - `E_SUCCESS` — The method is successful.
  - `E_INVALID_STATE` — The file has not been opened as yet.
  - `E_ILLEGAL_ACCESS` — The file is not opened for write operation, or access is denied due to insufficient permission.
  - `E_INVALID_ARG` — Either of the following conditions has occurred:

    - The specified buffer contains a null pointer.
    - The specified buffer length is equal or smaller than 0.
    - The file handle is invalid (either the file is closed by another method, or the memory is corrupted).
  - `E_STORAGE_FULL` — The disk space is full.
  - `E_IO` — An unexpected device failure has occurred as the media ejected suddenly or file corruption is detected.

I'd rather not assume that there will be any sort of buffering, although I am confident each byte won't occasion a whole block of flash to be rewritten but I was wondering if there is a niftier way to write all the data fields of a class (and nothing else, eg static fields) by, eg, a pointer to the object (`*this`)?

Comment: So you're asking if C++ has any built-in serialization mechanisms for classes and structs?

Comment: I don't think C++ >> stream operators are available to me. @Cody, yes, as long as you don't mean << and >>

Comment: Most C++ structs cannot be serialized bitwise, you'll have to use streams or similar.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm missing the question completely, but couldn't you just do Osp::Io::File::Write(&SomeObj, sizeof(SomeObj))?  Hopefully you're just serializing POD types.

Comment: @JonG. Yup, that's what I thought, but now I remember leaving a `Osp::Base::String` in there too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++ you don't write "raw" objects into files, but rather *serialize* them. There's no magic, you need to write your serialization code yourself (overloading operators `<<` and `>>`, for convenience).

You can do it the old C-style by just dumping memory, but in addition to the problems this would generally cause with C (alignment, endian issues when transferring data between systems), you also get the problems introduced by C++ (internal class representation, possible "hidden" data members such as a v-table, etc).

If you want to ensure you read and write reliable data that can be transferred between different systems and/or different pieces of software - you better implement the serialization, and don't look for shortcuts.

You can use libraries like [Boost.Serialization](http://www.boost.org/libs/serialization/) for that.

Comment: OK, I found a non POD member that would have mucked up my plan anyhoo.

Comment: Writing raw objects into files is nothing you "don't" do in C++, for PODs it's often the most effective solution. For many other types of data it's not, but the standard stream operators are also not good for all kind of data.

Comment: @leftaroundabout +1 agree 100% with your statement - PODs are great for maximizing efficiency in C++, block writes, copies, etc...